# Change activities without having a transition effect

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to know how you could switch between activities without having that sort of "transition effect" that you have when you switch as usual like `startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this, Target.class))`, as if you were navigating in the same activity.
I have this bottom navbar

---

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    app:itemBackground="@color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
    app:menu="@menu/footer" />
```

where `@menu/footer` is defined as:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:title="@string/bacheca"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/cerca"
    android:title="@string/cerca"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_black_24dp"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/nuovo"
    android:title="@string/nuovo"
    android:icon="@drawable/add_circle_outline_black_400_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"
/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/profilo"
    android:title="@string/profilo"
    android:icon="@drawable/account_circle_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"
/>
```

The visual effect is this:

[image]

By tapping on each section, I would switch between "contextes" (or, effectively, activities) having the previous activity left intact, with all the insert data and the scroll position.

Answer (score 1):

You should override pending transition immediately after starting activity.you can use this code

```
startActivity(new Intent(Activity.this, Target.class))
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

but i suggest you to use activity with multiple fragment to achieve sections with multiple pages and tabBar.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach to achieve this effect is to use a single Activity with Fragments to replace the part of the view that you want to change.